# Process of List.generate Constructor in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and Dart. I am trying to create long List View in Flutter. but I am stuck with this `Constructor`. Can anyone explain how this Constructor works?

```
List<String> = List<String>.generate(1000,(counter) => "Item $counter");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following:

```
List<String>.generate(1000,(counter) => "Item $counter");
```

will generate a `List` of 1000 items, where each item are in order:

```
"Item 0"
"Item 1"
"Item 2"
...
"Item 999"
```

Comment: So what is the counter in fat arrow function . ?

Comment: It is the index of the item

Comment: is there a way to start the list form 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @Ankit, List<String>.generate(1000,(counter) => "Item ${counter + 1}");

Answer (score 5):

```
List<String> = List<String>.generate(1000,(counter) => "Item $counter");
```

this will generate 1000 item and you can manipulate each item threw your arrow  function that takes  counter as a parameter in that case counter will be ur index each time . 
the output will be :

```
"Item 0"
"Item 1"
"Item 2"
...
"Item 999"
```

Answer (score 2):

`List.generate` can be very useful if you know the length and structure of the list you like to create.
For example: You can create a List of  maps too

Here generating a list with day e.g Mon, Tue,Wed,etc.. for the whole week
see the 7 as the number of iterations.

```
      final myList = List.generate(7, (index) {
            final dateFormatted =DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:index));
                return {
                    'day':DateFormatted.E().format(dateF),
                    'date':dateFormatted,
             };
             });
        print(myList);
```